# Segfault on PDO::beginTransaction when extending PDO class

Tags: php, inheritance, pdo, segmentation-fault

I made some changes to my DB abstraction code, and now it's segfaulting, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

**Edit: I found the cause to my problem, and unfortunately it was nothing to do with what I wrote about in this question.  See my answer below for more details of what I messed up.**

My changes included changing from *encapsulating* the PDO object to inheriting from the PDO class.

eg from

```
class DBConnection {
  private $pdo;
```

to

```
class DBConnection extends PDO {
```

A segmentation fault now occurs during a call to `$db->beginTransaction();`.  Other database queries still work, and if I remove the offending call to `beginTransaction()` and its matching `commit()` it works fine.

Offending code:

```
  public function getdelay($action, $interval, $tolerance = 2) {
    ...
    $this->db->begintransaction();
    ...
```

The same code worked when I was encapsulating the PDO object instead of inheriting.

Using `gdb` I was able to get the following backtraces by attaching to the process and waiting until the segfault occurred (full backtrace begins at 6th line):

```
Core was generated by `php-fpm: pool www'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  memset (__len=<optimized out>, __ch=<optimized out>, __dest=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h:84
84      /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt full
#0  memset (__len=<optimized out>, __ch=<optimized out>, __dest=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h:84
No locals.
#1  i_create_execute_data_from_op_array (nested=<optimized out>, op_array=<optimized out>)
    at /build/php5-5.6.24+dfsg/Zend/zend_execute.c:1679
        execute_data = 0x7f2cf1e3a890
        CVs_size = 0
        Ts_size = 139831013517456
        total_size = 139831013517248
#2  zend_execute (op_array=0x7f2cf1e3a918, op_array@entry=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffcf6731048>)
    at /build/php5-5.6.24+dfsg/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:388
No locals.
```

Using version `5.6.24+dfsg-0+deb8u1` (Debian stable supplied version) running as PHP-FPM.

**My specific question**

What should I do now, in order to get my code working (beginTransaction working without segfaulting)?  Would it be best to go back to encapsulating so I avoid extending the PDO class?

Was it a bad idea to extend a native PHP class?  Is this likely to lead to weird issues?

Comment: I suspect you've overridden a method of the class that calls some driver initialization code, and as a result it's later using an uninitialized variable.

Comment: If you override a method, you need to make sure it does everything that the original method does, or call `parent::methodName()` to pass on to it.

Comment: There's no way to know specifically what you did wrong without seeing the code.

Comment: You should consider filing a bug at `bugs.php.net`

Comment: I just checked and every method I've overridden (basically just the constructor, and `query()`), includes a call to the parent method.

Comment: Constructor includes the code: `parent::__construct($dbsettings, $user, $pass, $extra);`

Comment: I'm happy with that reason for closing, thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of my problem, and it's embarrassingly simple.  It is not related to extending the PDO class.  Instead, it is related to me not realising that method names are case-insensitive.

My original database class had a function to begin a transaction:

```
function begintransaction() {
  ...
```

Notice that the 't' is lowercase.

When making the modifications to my database class, I put this in:

```
function begintransaction() {
  return $this->beginTransaction();
}
```

The intention behind this was to allow the all-lowercase `begintransaction` to continue to function where-ever it appeared in the old code, serving as a wrapper around PDO's `beginTransaction` (with capital 'T').

However, since method names are not case-sensitive in PHP, all this does is call itself, creating infinite recursion, which leads to a segmentation fault.

My skills in debugging a segmentation fault were poor enough that I did not realise this was due to infinite recursion.